# Multiple Dropbox accounts on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, dropbox, cloud-storage

I have Windows 8.1.  I have followed several different methods mentioned here and elsewhere but when I get to trying to put in my password, Windows will not let me type it in.

I have to have access to 4 different accounts for 4 different positions I hold.  I really hate having to share or using multiple usernames.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you thought about sharing the other accounts' files with your primary/own account?

Comment: @Mario a caveat of that is the required space will be the combination of all 4 accounts possibly but the allowed space will be only that of a single account.

Comment: @Damon I think they recently added the possibility to only download files just in time, which would avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the runas command in the Target box of the shortcut settings was working in windows 8, but no more in windows 8.1.

To run a shortcut as a different user in 8.1 you need to add the shortcut to the taskbar and with [shift][rightmouse] you can enter the alternative username and pass to run it as alternative user inside the primary user account.

I hope this clears thing up a bit, now I have two dropboxes running simultaniously in 8.1 so problem solved for me.